# How can I solve this error while importing inflect package?

Tags: python

I tried to run the code in inflect documentation https://pypi.org/project/inflect/ but I get a value error.

```
import inflect

p = inflect.engine()

word = 'cat'
cat_count = 10

print("The plural of ", word, " is ", p.plural(word))
print("I saw", cat_count, p.plural("cat", cat_count))
```

I get the error:

`` ValueError: `Field` default cannot be set in `Annotated` for 'num_Annotated[str, FieldInfo(min_length=1, extra={})]' ``

I tried deleting and reinstalling the package but nothing changed. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug with your version ([source](https://github.com/coqui-ai/TTS/issues/1808)).